# What is regular expression to get token in a json?

Tags: regex

I try to get token in a json to put it in Bearer token to run jmeter, but it does not get the correct content which i want.

Json likes this:

```
{"access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","token_type":.......}
```

I want to get the **xxxxxxxxxx** only.

I try with regular: `\"access_token":"([^\:]*)\"`, but it returns "**access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx**".

Please help me to have the correct regular expression.
Thanks.

Comment: That regex might be ok - but you're looking at the whole match rather than the first capturing group.  Whatever you're using to do the regex should have a way of accessing capturing groups.  As an aside - are you sure there isn't a way to process json natively in your environment?

Comment: What tool/language are you using? It's better to use a parser.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex is the wrong tool for the job!** You've already got JSON - it makes much more sense to use a JSON parser. However, if you insist on using regex, the following should work: `"access_token":"([^"]*)"`

This regex finds the `access_token` key, and then captures all data up to the first closing `"`. Note that this will break if `"` appears inside the data being captured. Also note that `"` does not need to be escaped in a regex (but may need to be escaped due to the language you're using).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQFWbH/1/)